# Can I use a database from Laravel 3 with Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel

I'd love to take down our laravel3 app since it's mainly an api as angular has replaced a lot of blade templates.

Our DB was built up in Laravel 3, but can I just switch to laravel 4 without modifying my tables?

Comment: You might want to bring the Laravel 4 app up in a subdomain first instead of just switching. (Assuming you can reach your database from the subdomain.) You probably already thought of that, but others who read this . . .

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' That's excellent input.  Easy way to test in production while building in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can switch. I have switched in the past with no problems.  Remember, Laravel is just a framework.  Any "defaults" can be changed with how Laravel interprets your tables.